# Rails 3: Developing Facebook Applications Book/Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a good book/resource about developing FB apps using roR?

There's a pragprog book but it's outdated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only rails plugin that I've found that works with the graph api is https://github.com/mmangino/facebooker2 . I haven't found any great resources, but using the readme and code and looking at the parent project https://github.com/mmangino/mogli I was able to implement everything I needed so far.

Answer (score 0):

You also have this gem https://github.com/arsduo/koala/ that provides you "A lightweight, flexible library for Facebook with support for OAuth authentication, the Graph and REST APIs, realtime updates, and test users" [copy from the referred github page]